# reusing windows 10 digital key

Tags: windows-10, license, bloatware

to the point:

- brand new laptop with windows 10 Pro.
- I will reinstall windows from scratch and remove all the bloatware (hp wolfsecurity and sureclick, looking at ya)
- I got the windows 10 pro key from registry.
- I do not plan to ever have a windows account on microsoft.com

Q: can I simply wipe the storage, install windows from a clean microsoft provided image, and reuse the key on the same hardware?

Comment: I have just received a brand new Dell Vostro with Win 11 Pro. I need to swop out the 512GB SSD for a 2TB one. I thus am in the same situation as you. I tried `slmgr /dli` to get the key, but only 5 characters are shown. Is there another method to extract the product key?

Comment: i don't think i needed to use the key to reinstall, so you should be fine without it. I think the key is present somewhere in bios or other storage. I wiped the drive completely and reinstalled.

Comment: As far as I understand, a fingerprint of some "hash" of the hardware details is captured when you first activate a key. This is stored at Microsoft. When you reinstall, and if the hardware hasn't changed too much, it should match the fingerprint, and there is no need for a key to activate. I wanted the key, just in case the fingerprint process isn't that accurate.

Comment: if your key is invalidated with a hardware change you are screwed with or without a key i guess. but i did extract the key from registry pretty easily, just did not write down the method. i think it was the very first search result for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I simply wipe the storage, install windows from a clean microsoft
> provided image, and reuse the key on the same hardware?

Yes you can do this (OEM or Retail Key - it does not matter). The key is maintained in the Microsoft Licensing System and the license provides for reinstalling on the same drive or replacing the drive.

So just install the same version of Windows (Home or Pro) and that will work fine.

You will likely need some drivers from the laptop Manufacturer’s Support Site

Comment: the microsoft website makes a huge deal about "digital license" not being a key. thanks

Comment: The digital license and the license server is a significant part of making the license reusable on the same hardware

Comment: i think i understood it wrong before. when you say "Licensing System and the license provides for reinstalling" does that mean my hardware "ID" will just magically get a license again after reinstall? or that i can reuse the key i extracted with the same hardware ID?

Comment: The licensing system uses the hardware key to make sure the same hardware is being used.

Comment: @gcb - Windows will automatically detect your license key and automatically activate.